# How do you get http:// to load automatically in a web browser?

Tags: application-development

i have created a web browser in glade / python and what i'm wanting to do is get HTTP:// to load automatically.  Just because at the moment whenever i go to a website i have to type the HTTP:// and if i do not type this then the website does not open and i get a error message.

could anyone please help me out with the code or a way to do this please.

Comment: It works in Firefox.  Have you tried `Ctrl+Enter`?

Comment: Just add a list of protocols (http, https, ftp, etc) and require that the leading blob be one of them.  If it's not prepend the default to the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the address entry is called `address_entry`, try it like this:

```
url = address_entry.get_text()
if not "://" in url:
    # Is http a sane prefix?
    url = "http://" + url
```

Comment: cheers for that i just got it working tonight i was playing about with some code and it started working.

self.webview.open("http://" + url)

that is the code that got it to work for me

Comment: @DriftedMass: that doesn't sound like a solution to me. What if the user already typed `http://`? You end up with an invalid `http://http://www.ubuntu.com`.

Comment: python is so nice!

Comment: So if the user had already typed http:// how do you suggest that i cancel out the script running the http:// bit?

Comment: @DriftedMass: see my answer. It will only add `http://` if the string `://` isn't found in the url.

Comment: Awww thats what i have now done @timo i looked through my code and found the bit that stated the url and added "http://" + url to it